# What is better way to query mongodb array field?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb. So I don't know what is the better way to query array field. I have a schema where in our collection of courses we have a program field. In start it was Reference to program collection and contain program id. But Now we have change the schema from Reference to array of Reference, so we can allow course to be a part of multiple program. In our codebase all the query are written like this:

```
course.find({program});
```

Do I have to change this query to cater this schema change like this:

```
course.find({program: {$in: program}});
```

I have tested in mongodb compass and this query

```
course.find({program});
```

Work on array field.

So let me know what could be consequence if i don't use $in operator while search the array field.

Comment: Operator `$in` requires an array. If the array holds only one element then you can use either ways of query.

Comment: Currently array would have one value but in future there would be multiple values in array.